# Sub panel cable feed code

Tags: subpanel

The inspector failed the sub panel box location because it only had 6 feet clearance and not 6.5.  The electricians came and moved the sub panel box, but they did not run a new feed cable.  They put a junction box and added the rest of the run from the junction box to the new panel location. The box is in  a utility room so it is not hidden and is proper that way.  Is it proper as per code and good common sense to spit the feeder cable to the sub panel that way?

Comment: Don't think there's anything in code that says a feeder has to be continuous.

Comment: What is your location? Which clearance are you referring, headroom, approach, side? NEC doesn't prohibit splicing the feeders as long as the overall installation of the feeders comply with code. When you hired the electricians did you question how they would re-feed the panel. Did the inspector refer the electricians? I can't think of many installations where you would need more than 6' clearance in any direction per National Electric Code.